# Adding shared fields to a SharePoint calendar to sync with an Outlook calendar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, outlook, calendar, customcolumn

I have set up MOSS 2007 Enterprise with a calendar that I have added custom columns to.  We have synced this calendar in Outlook, and it works great creating and editing events from either SharePoint or Outlook.

The issue is that I want to be able to add two extra fields to the New Event form in Outlook that I have added to the SharePoint Calendar.  I went into Outlook's Form Designer. I go to the second tab to add the extra data fields, but I can't figure out how to be able to map to those two extra fields for the SharePoint calendar.

What's the best way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do sync customized fields. I can programming this sync, using empty  standard fields, like "mileage".

Comment: I guess this is my answer, but I'm not happy with the functionality  that I'm needing not being built into MOSS 2007.

Comment: any idea if this does this still apply for SharePoint 2010 and Outlook 2016 sync?

Answer (score 1):

This limitation has plagued my consulting firm for years. Many of our clients are surprised when they cannot find their custom fields. It got to the point where we decided to develop our own Outlook add-in to bridge the gap.

The project is now known as ProperSync and is available for public download. We hope it helps those who are looking for custom fields within Outlook. At the moment it works for calendar and task lists, but we are working on other Outlook types as well. You can find more at www.propersync.com